# How to delete files matching a certain pattern in their name?

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I'm creating a batch file that deletes all `Rar$DIa0.???` folders in the `%TEMP%` directory.

Is this possible, and how to do it?

The ??? is three randomized numbers. And that's where I have trouble with - deleting all folders that have `Rar$DIa0.` in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line to use in a batch file for this task is:

```
@for /D %%I in ("%TEMP%\Rar$DIa0.*") do @rd /Q /S "%%I"
```

Command **FOR** with option `/D` searches in folder defined by environment variable `TEMP` for subfolders with folder name starting with `Rar$DIa0.` not having hidden or system attribute set.

The loop variable `I` holds for each found subfolder matching this folder pattern the name of found folder with full path without double quotes although the path to temp folder very often contains 1 or more spaces.

For that reason just the command **RD** with the parameters `/Q` for quiet execution and `/S` for deleting also all subfolders in the specified folder must be called with referencing the current value of loop variable `I` enclosed in double quotes.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `rd /?`

By the way: *WinRAR* deletes the temporary folders usually automatically, except a file is opened from within an archive for viewing/modifying it in another application and *WinRAR* is closed before the other application is exited with the opened file. In this case *WinRAR* can't delete the temporary folder with temporarily extracted file because the file is still opened in another application. Of course also command **RD** can't delete the temporary folder if this folder is still the current directory of another application or a file in this folder is still opened by another application with a read/write access lock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it actually works! I implemented this into my batch file. I have a new problem: deleting these folders from C:\$RECYCLE.BIN. Is there any way to do this without manually deleting them? I don't want to delete all of the files, I want to leave everything except for these folders. I have already tried **del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$Dla0.*"** which didn't work.

Comment: The command __DEL__ is for deleting files. The command __RD__ (remove directory) is for deleting folders. That is clearly stated in first line of help output by running `del /?` and `rd /?` in a command prompt window. In same batch file make a copy of posted command line and replace in second command line `%TEMP%` by `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` to delete all folders matching pattern `Rar$Dla0.*` in recycle bin folder. Or use a single command line: `@for /D %%I in ("%TEMP%\Rar$DIa0.*" "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$DIa0.*") do @rd /Q /S "%%I"`

Answer (score 1):

`for /d` is designed for just this type of use. Something like this should work (remove one of the `%` if you're testing from the command line):

```
for /d %%i in ("%TEMP%\Rar$DIa0.???") do rd "%TEMP%\%%i"
```

The /d makes it work on directory names instead of file names.

If you want to make it easier on yourself, change to the %TEMP% folder first:

```
pushdir
cd /d %TEMP%
for /d %%i in ("Rar$DIa0.???") do rd "%%i"
```

The `???` makes it only act on folders that have three letters after a `.`. If your folders don't have just a three letter extension, change `.???` to `.*`. If you've got a typo, and there is no actual `.` in the foldername, just remove it and use `Rar$DIa0???` or `Rar$DIa0*`

You may want to test it first by changing `rd` to `echo` to make sure you get the folders you want before actually deleting them.

For more information about `for` (pun intended) type `for /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: "for /d %%i in (Rar$DIa0*) do rd %%i" doesn't work. It doesn't delete folders.

Comment: (Rar$DIa0) was unexpected at this time.

Comment: It does work. I tested it here first before posting. Your second comment is missing the wildcard (either ? or *). The only reason `rd` won't work is if the directories are not empty, in which case you need to use `rd /s %%i`. or if you've done something other than what I posted. Learn to use the help system built in to Windows commands, accessed by using the command name followed with `/?`, as I showed you in my answer.

Comment: Or you've got spaces in your directory names, in which case you need to surround them in double-quotes, as in ("Rar$DIa0*").

Comment: for /d %%i in (Rar$DIa0*) do rd /f %%i - this doesn't delete the folder in %TEMP%. Is it a problem with temp?

Comment: I assumed you were already in `%TEMP%`. I'll change it. Hang on.

Comment: In your 2nd code there seems to be a typo, the leading backslash shoul be removed...

Comment: @aschipfl: Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it actually works! I implemented this into my batch file. I have a new problem: deleting these folders from C:\$RECYCLE.BIN. Is there any way to do this without manually deleting them? I don't want to delete all of the files, I want to leave everything except for these folders. I have already tried del /s /q "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\Rar$Dla0.*" which didn't work.

Comment: @Quizzed: If you have a new problem, start a new question and ask it there. This question has been answered.